# Error in generating C code from GSM-TCAP asn1 files

Tags: c, parsing, asn.1, ss7

I am trying to generate C code for the GSM-TCAP asn1 files obtained from [libosmo-asn1-TCAP](http://git.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-tcap/). I have installed the [osmocom libasnc1](https://github.com/osmocom/libasn1c) compiler (tried both master and aper-prefix branches) and run this code:

```
asn1c -fcompound-names -gen-PER 
       DialoguePDUs.asn 
       tcap.asn 
       TCAPMessages.asn 
       TC-Notation-Extensions.asn 
       UnidialoguePDUs.asn
```

However, the compiler reports the following syntax error:

```
ASN.1 grammar parse error near line 86 (token "returnResult"): syntax error, 
unexpected TOK_identifier Cannot parse "TCAPMessages.asn"
```

Does anyone know the root of this problem, and how to resolve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to compile all asn files in asn sub-directory. There is a [rebuild script](http://git.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-tcap/tree/src/rebuild-from-asn.sh) that you could use.

```
asn1c $ASN/DialoguePDUs.asn $ASN/tcap.asn $ASN/UnidialoguePDUs.asn
```

The other files contain syntax that is not supported by `asn1c` and some of them were rewritten to not use such syntax and some are not needed at all.

Comment: Vasko, thanks for your answer. Are these three files sufficient to implement the normal procedures in the mobile Core Network? It would be great if you could also help in the regard of this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53632962/problem-in-compiling-c-code-generated-by-the-osmocom-asn1c)

Comment: I believe they are sufficient