# Problem in compiling C code generated by osmocom asn1c

Tags: c, ss7, asn.1

I have installed the [osmocom asn1c compiler](https://github.com/osmocom/asn1c/tree/aper-prefix), the `aper-prefix` branch, to obtain an implementation of the TCAP protocol.
I have used the [respective script](http://git.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-tcap/tree/src/rebuild-from-asn.sh) to compile the ".asn" files.
The C files are generated successfully, but when compiling the obtained C code, an error is raised, which is related to this line of code:

```
#include <EXTERNAL.h>
```

In fact, the file EXTERNAL.h is missing (seemingly, the EXTERNAL type is not supported by this compiler). 
Is anyone aware of this problem and a possible solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options:

1. Use a [newer version of asn1c from this PR](https://github.com/vlm/asn1c/pull/295)  (still not merged)
2. Copy the [EXTERNAL.h](http://git.osmocom.org/libosmo-asn1-tcap/tree/include/EXTERNAL.h) from the osmocom repository
3. Rename `EXTERNAL` to `EXTERNALt` in all asn files and add the following in the asn files that has EXTERNALt.

   ```
   --
   -- From "ITU-T Recommendation X.208", "34 The external type"
   --
   EXTERNALt ::= [UNIVERSAL 8] IMPLICIT SEQUENCE
   {direct-reference OBJECT IDENTIFIER OPTIONAL,
       indirect-reference INTEGER OPTIONAL,
       data-value-descriptor ObjectDescriptor OPTIONAL,
       encoding CHOICE
       {single-ASN1-type [0] ANY,
           octet-aligned [1] IMPLICIT OCTET STRING,
           arbitrary [2] IMPLICIT BIT STRING}}
   ```

   Or add it in a separate asn file and import where needed.